# Is my code okay or did I make it way too complicated?

Tags: python

I recently started coding and I love it.
I'm currently working on a few tasks (for beginners lol) and just came up with the following: 'Find the second greatest element in a list'

I did the following:

```py
def second_greatest(list):
    length = len(list)
    if length <= 1:
        return(list)
    else:
        greatest = max(list[0], list[1])
        s_greatest = min(list[0], list[1])
        for i in range (2, length):
            if list[i] > greatest:
                s_greatest = greatest
                greatest = list[i]
            elif list[i] > s_greatest and greatest != list[i]:
                s_greatest= list[i]

        return(s_greatest)
```

I found this solution on the web:

```py
def example(example_list, k):
    for i in range(k-1):
        example_list.remove(max(example_list))
    return (max(example_list))
```

I feel like an idiot, because my code looks too complicated compared to the second one...
If we have a relatively large number (e.g. find 1438th greatest), I would definitely go with solution 2..
But I'm wondering which solution is better (faster) for this particular question (find second greatest value)?

Comment: Are the values unique? What if you have `[1,2,3,3]` what would you consider the second greatest?

Comment: I would consider '2' as the second greatest. I just tried it on both func... now I see it lol

Comment: I would consider the second example bad, it mutates the input, and uses a relatively expensive algorithm to find the answer, despite its tersness. Don't be fooled into thinking "terse == good". It isn't

Comment: Calling the built-in `max()` function will be faster than anything you could write, both in development time and execution time. That is why a thorough acquaintance  with built-in methods and the standard library is so important. You don't have to know the whole of the standard library by heart (I don't,  and I don't know anyone who does), but being able to ask yourself *Isn’t there a library module that does that?* is a key to being productive and happy.

Comment: Thank's for the answers!! :) good advises

Comment: If you have working code that you would like reviewed, use [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) *not* this site.

Comment: @martineau I didn't know this site.. thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options

The obvious one: sorting the unique values and getting the second to last (O(n*log(n)) complexity sure to the sorting):

```
l = [2,4,1,2,4,0,1,4,2]

sorted(set(l))[-2]
```

A maybe better option that is O(n):

```
def second_greatest(lst):
    MAX1 = MAX2 = -float('inf')
    for item in lst:
        if item > MAX1:
            MAX2 = MAX1
            MAX1 = item 
        if MAX1 > item >= MAX2:
            MAX2 = item
    return MAX2
```

Output: `2`

*NB. There is no validation of the input here, but of course the first option requires to ensure that there are at least 2 unique items, the second one would return -inf for less than 2 unique items.*

Comment: thank you! I get your first example... I'm struggling with the second one... I'm taking a closer look at it this evening

Comment: I used slightly more explicit variable names

Comment: Yes.. I noticed that. I’m coding for a few days now and I'm struggling with this: 'MAX1 = MAX2 = -float('inf')'

Comment: This is just a shortcut to initialize both MAX1 and MAX2 to -inf

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is even more faster and also easier to read for you as beginner:

```
def second_greatest(list):
    if len(list)>1:
        return sorted(list)[-2]
    else:
        return list[0]

mylst = [1,2,3,89,90,23]


print(second_greatest(mylst))
```

Hope this is helping you!

Comment: Thank you! It really helps to see other approaches! :) Just one question: why did you sorted it after len(list) == 1?

Comment: Do you really need to sort of you have only one element? Also per OP's requirement the second greatest **unique** value should be returned ;)

Comment: Supposing your list contains unique numbers you just sort it from the lower to the bigger one and get the one just before the last one. There is no problem with the speed since it runs only once because sorted takes place in the return statement so there is no problem. Notice also that if there are not unique items inside list you should do something like sorted(list(set(mylist))) because set makes them unique.

Comment: @mozway You are right, just updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: everyone starts somewhere, so don't feel bad.

Second: Yes, your code is a bit more complicated than it needs to be.

Third: The solution you found, it has so many issues. Did you test it?

- It is the opposite of what you are looking for
- The () around the last line is not needed (on yours too), it should be

  return max(example_list)
- Why is there even a second parameter? This makes no sense.
- It is written really clever so I actually had to test it to know what exactly is going on.

You getting there and your code is not that bad for a beginner.
A really important advice: try to not use protected keywords (used by the language itself) like "list", that's why its orange in the preview.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer :) The idea with the second parameter was the following: If we would like to know which one is the second greatest, we first need to know which is the greatest..that's why i differentiated between second greatest & greatest and put both in two different parameters

Comment: @user18774787 Your code in the first solution had speaking variables and was kinda okay. The "solution from the web" is even in this regard worse, because the parameter names are not speaking, meaning i can't tell what they are for anymore. In your more complicated version the variable names are okay.

I mean could be better like list could be _list for not using a protected keyword and s_greatest could be second_greatest, but the function name is already second_greatest so its fine.